# Suggestions on how I can optimize this MySQL query to run faster

Tags: mysql, optimization

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   members 
WHERE  memberid IN (SELECT follows.followingid 
                    FROM   follows 
                    WHERE  follows.memberid = '$memberid' 
                           AND follows.followingid NOT IN (SELECT memberid 
                                                           FROM   userblock)) 
       AND memberid NOT IN (SELECT blockmemberid 
                            FROM   userblock 
                            WHERE  memberid = '$memberid')
```

The query above is taking nearly 4 seconds to execute in MySQL and I want to know if anyone has any suggestions on how I might improve/optimize it to achieve a faster execution time?

Comment: I'd like to ask "Why?" Could you please elaborate on logic of this query? Maybe it should be completely replaced with a better one.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? MySQL is very poor in the area of subqueries optimization.

Comment: @Malkocoglu I am trying to search for the value memberid in tables that have a relationship with it in the 'follows' table. I then want to filter out any values where that relationship occurs in the userblock table.

Comment: @zavg I am using MySQL version 5.5.30

Comment: I think there is a logical problem. How are you using userblock table? Is userblock.memberid is the person who blocks others? And userblock.blockmemberid is the blocked person.

Comment: **Show us the table and index definitions.**

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `in` clauses with joins.  I think the following captures the logic.  Note that the `not in` turns into a `left join` with a condition in the `where` clause finding a non-match

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM members m
     follow f
     on m.memberid = f.followingid and 
        f.memberid = $memberid left join
     userblock ubf
     on follows.followingid = ubf.memberid left join
     userblock ub
     on m.memberid = ub.blockmemberid and
        ub.memberid = '$memberid'
where ub.blockmemberid is null and
      ubf.memberid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar but you have less nested queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   members m
WHERE  EXIST (SELECT f.followingid 
              FROM   follows f
              WHERE  f.memberid = '$memberid'
                     AND f.followingid = m.memberid)

       AND NOT EXIST (SELECT u.blockmemberid 
                      FROM   userblock u
                      WHERE  (m.memberid = '$memberid'
                             AND u.blockmemberid = m.memberid)
                          OR 
                             (u.blockmemberid = m.memberid
                             AND u.memberid = m.memberid) )
```

This is the logic I reversed-engineered from your code without seeing tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM   members m
INNER JOIN follows f ON f.followingid = m.memberid AND
                        f.memberid = '$memberid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN userblock ub1 ON f.followingid = ub1.memberid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN userblock ub2 ON m.memberid = ub2.blockmemberid AND
                            ub2.memberid = '$memberid'
WHERE ub1.memberid IS NULL AND ub2.blockmemberid IS NULL
```